# Is there a 'GPS status changed' event for html5 geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, gps, w3c-geolocation

I'm developing a web app for mobile and using html5's geolocation api.

When the page is loaded I start a watch position:

```js
function enableWatchPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        watchPositionId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(locateByBrowser, handleErrorGettingLocation, {
            timeout : 30000,
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            maximumAge : 1000
        });
    }
}
```

If a user doesn't have his GPS on, `handleErrorGettingLocation` is triggered and I show him an error message, asking him to turn GPS on.

My Question is:
Suppose the user then turns his GPS on - how can I detect that (so I could retry and call `enableWatchPosition()` again)? Is there some sort of js event I can listen to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event that’s exposed in a way you could see from your Web-application code. Certainly there is no such event defined in the standard [Geolocation API spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). And I don’t believe there are any non-standard events that any browsers expose for it. So I don’t think you’re going to be able to automatically re-trigger a call to your `enableWatchPosition()` function.

I’m sure that’s not the answer you were hoping for, but it is the answer. :-(

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wonder if it will be added in the future as it is a missing feature. Thanks anyway.